# sed (on osx Snow Leopard) with BRE '.' doesn't match character > ascii 127

Tags: regex, macos, sed, bsd, env

I'm running sed on Mac Os X Snow Leopard.

sed is/should be BSD sed (man page is dated 2005-05-10)
man page states:

```
The sed utility is expected to be a superset of 
the IEEE Std 1003.2 (``POSIX.2'') specification.
```

When I'm trying a replacement, and the input stream holds characters larger than ascii 127, the dot does not match this character.

e.g.

```
echo -e "a001\0001a - a127\0177a - a128\0200a - a255\0377a - a061\0075a" \
| sed -e 's/a[0-9]\{3\}.a/match/g;' ;
echo "result: $?";
```

results in output:

```
match - match - a128?a - a255?a - match
result: 0
```

On Os X Maverick (stating the same manual page), the result gives an error:

```
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
result: 1
```

On a linux Mint 13 system, the same instruction returns (my expectation):

```
match - match - match - match - match
result: 0
```

according to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03 the '.' should match

```
"any character in the supported character set except NUL".
```

If running this similar command (gsed version 4.2.1 on Os X Snow Leopard):

```
echo -e "a001\0001a - a127\0177a - a128\0200a - a255\0377a - a061\0075a"\
| gsed -e 's/a[0-9]\{3\}.a/match/g;';
echo "result: $?";
```

I get the same (for me unexpected) result:

```
match - match - a128?a - a255?a - match
result: 0
```

1. anybody else has the same behaviour ?
2. can explain why ? (is it a bug in BSD ??) and/or how to circumvent/fix ?
   I can only guess it is related to the "`supported character set`"
   which would then be different on the different systems....
   Especially since on the SL-system both BSD sed and GNU sed behave the same.
   I did however already check and alter my env:
   On the SL system:

   ```
   $> env | grep '^L'
   LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   LANGUAGE=en_US:en
   LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
   ```

   And on the Mint system:

   ```
   $user@Mint > env | grep '^L'
   LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   LANGUAGE=en_US:en
   LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your locale is UTF-8, but the byte sequence you are echoing is not valid UTF-8, because of `\0200a` and `\0377a`. If you use set `LC_ALL=en_US.ISO8859-1` (iso-latin-1), then it works fine, because the result of `echo` is a valid iso-latin-1 string.

Comment: Note that LC_ALL must be set in the `sed` command's environment. This can be accomplished by setting it in the shell and exporting it (`export LC_ALL=en_US.ISO8859-1` -- which sets it for the shell and all commands the shell runs) or using it as a prefix for the `sed` command (`LC_ALL=en_US.ISO8859-1 sed ...` -- which sets it only for the `sed` command itself).